# C++ MySQL Header files not found (Linux Application)

Tags: c++, mysql

I am trying to connect to my local MySQL database hosted via XAMPP.

I downloaded this .zip file https://cdn.mysql.com//Downloads/Connector-C++/mysql-connector-c++-8.0.20-winx64.zip and I added the include folder to the field in C/C++->General/Additional Includes and of course the lib64 folder to the field in Linker->Input->Additional dependencies + Linker->General->Additional Library Directories.
Shall I download the MySQL Server (I have only installed XAMPP with MySQL)?

This is a Linux Console Application and I am running this with gdb on my WSL and I am running it in release x64 mode!

Code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include "mysql_connection.h"
#include "mysql_driver.h"

#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>

int main()
{
    try
    {
        sql::Driver* driver;
        sql::Connection* con;

        driver = get_driver_instance();
        con = driver->connect("tcp://localhost:3306", "root", "");
        con->setSchema("botcaptcha");
    }
    catch (sql::SQLException& err)
    {
        printf(err.what());
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
1>C:\Users\JanDerZocker05\Desktop\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\main.cpp(2,10): error : mysql_connection.h: No such file or directory
1>C:\Users\JanDerZocker05\Desktop\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\main.cpp(2,10): error :     2 | #include "mysql_connection.h"
1>C:\Users\JanDerZocker05\Desktop\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\main.cpp(2,10): error :       |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1>C:\Users\JanDerZocker05\Desktop\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\main.cpp(2,10): error : compilation terminated.
1>Die Erstellung des Projekts "ConsoleApplication2.vcxproj" ist abgeschlossen -- FEHLER
```

includes:

[image: includes]

library directories:

[image: library directories]

libraries:

[image: libraries]

Comment: I commented only to encourage you to post an answerable question, not to say that I would then be able to answer it personally. Also, it looks like your 1st image is not of your include settings, but rather a duplicate of your library path settings.

Comment: fixed that now!

Comment: If anyone reads it who can answer, the will. You don't get to just keep reposting the same question if you don't get as much attention as you want. I've flagged the others as duplicates.

Comment: of course you can do that, but my friend has also experienced the same shit

Comment: @HerrHass Please don't blame others if you and your friend use the site wrong. Use it like it is intended to be used: Edit your existing question to give more context, don't post a new one. This will get it bumped to "active". (Don't do this too often just to get views, though, that will get you into trouble. Each edit should be substantial.)

Comment: I know that but it's just frustrating. I am watching other threads and only 10% of them are getting answered...

Comment: That is not an excuse to repost the exact same question over and over again. If you [edit] the question, it will be bumped to the top of the feed to receive a bit more attention. Reposting is counter to the site's policies and may prevent you from asking more questions in the future. Note also that this site is run by volunteers. It is improper to expect an answer promptly.

Comment: Considering that you're the one who's new here, maybe you should _heed our advice_ instead of taking a defensive stance. We aren't here to bash you, but your expectations are pretty unaligned for the site, and need to be adjusted if you are interested in having a positive experience.

Comment: Nah, I won't use this site in the future

Comment: Suit yourself. Don't be a stranger.

Comment: @HerrHass Ok. Feel free to come back someday, we don't hold a grudge ;)